# How can I detect if the mouse is being moved to the left or right?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to detect the left and right mouse movements for a control - like you can use delta for up/down movement. Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

```
If e.x > 0 Then 'moved right
 msgbox("Moved right!")
else 'moved left
 msgbox("Moved left!")
End If
```

Comment: where is the code you have tried?  what events are you consuming?

Comment: e.x is always positive (except if the mouse is hold down)

Comment: e - the MouseEvent args is showing the **current** location.  save e.x and e.y to a module level variable so that you can compare e.X to oldLocation.X.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private oldXY As Point = Point.Empty

Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, 
       e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove

    If e.X < oldXY.X Then
        ' ....
    ElseIf e.X > oldXY.X Then
        ' ...
    End If
    oldXY.X = e.X
    oldXY.Y = e.Y
End Sub
```

You will likely want to add a test for Point.Empty so that you dont misreport the first mousemove.  Or try to initialize it to `Cursor.Position` to start with

Answer (score 0):

```
Private firstTime As Boolean = False
Private oldX As Integer

Private Sub Button1_MouseEnter(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseEnter
    firstTime = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_MouseMove(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseMove
    If firstTime = True Then
        firstTime = False
    Else
        If e.X > oldX Then
            'moves right
        ElseIf e.X < oldX Then
            'moves left
        End If
    End If

    oldX = e.X
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Timer , and I get a good result

```
Dim lx As Integer = 0 ' last x position
Dim ly As Integer = 0 ' last y position

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim x As Integer = MousePosition.X
    Dim y As Integer = MousePosition.Y
    Dim s As String = ""
    If x > lx Then
        s &= "Right,"
    ElseIf x < lx Then
        s &= "Left,"
    ElseIf x = lx Then
        s &= "No Change,"
    End If
    If y > ly Then
        s &= "Down"
    ElseIf y < ly Then
        s &= "Top"
    ElseIf y = ly Then
        s &= "No Change"
    End If
    lx = x
    ly = y
    Label1.Text = s
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I want to avoid using timers where possible.