# How can I detect the direction of a dragging event?

Tags: c#, mouseevent, mousedown, mouseup

So I have a `PictureBox` and the user is supposed to drag the cursor inside it towards the direction shown by the arrow (in the `PictureBox`), but I'm not sure how I will set the coordinates to make sure the user dragged in the correct direction (up, down, right, or left).

```
    private void picArrow_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        mPointDown = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        //lblTest.Text = "X: " + mPointDown.X.ToString() + "   Y: " + mPointDown.Y.ToString();

    }

    private void picArrow_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        lblTest.Text += "              " + " X: " + e.X.ToString() + "      Y: " + e.Y.ToString();

        //MessageBox.Show("Entered mouseup");
        //rnd_Arr refers to the number of the arrow being shown, 0 = towards the right
        if (rnd_Arr == 0 && mPointDown.X >= 0 && mPointDown.Y >= 0 && e.X >= 40 && e.Y >= 0)
        {
             //some code
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("DONE!");

        }
    }
```

And I know this code doesn't work because even if the user drags down (when he's supposed to drag up), it still accepts it and increments the score.

- I'm not putting too much restrictions. It doesn't have to be in a perfectly straight line, or start and end in exact locations. As long as the user is dragging inside the `PictureBox` and dragging to the correct direction, or at least reaches the minimum length to make sure it is considerable that the user is dragging to the correct direction, like for example:
- The arrow shown is pointing to the right. The user doesn't have to drag all the way through the arrow, if he drags horizontally past 40px (and the whole length of the arrow is, say, 80px), then that'll add a point to his score. Nevertheless, I'm deliberating this part, if I should just be more demanding and require the user to drag all the way through.
- Should I remove the mouse events for the `PictureBox` and add mouse events for the form instead?
  Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect if the mouse is being moved to the left or right?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734405/how-can-i-detect-if-the-mouse-is-being-moved-to-the-left-or-right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to check the MouseDown.X and compare it to the MouseUp.X (or Y if you want to check vertical direction as well). It is important to note that (0, 0) is the upper left of your screen.

Start by subtracting MouseUp.X from MouseDown.X to get a delta X. This is your change in X pixels over the move operation.

If your X comparison yields a negative delta (MouseUp.X is smaller than MouseDown.X), your mouse has moved left. 
If your X comparison yields a positive delta (MouseUp.X is larger than MouseDown.X), your mouse has moved right.

The same concept applies to the Y coord, positive change means you moved the mouse down and a negative changemeans you moved the mouse up. See below code:

```
Point mouseDownPoint;
Point mouseUpPoint;
float deltaX = mouseUpPoint.X - mouseDownPoint.X;
float deltaY = mouseUpPoint.Y - mouseDownPoint.Y;
if (deltaX > 0)
{
    // Moved right
}
else if (deltaX < 0)
{
     // Moved left
}
if (deltaY > 0)
{
     // Moved down
}
else if (deltaY < 0)
{
    // Moved up
}
```

Comment: I've deleted my previous comments as I've fixed the error. Thank you so much!

Comment: You bet, I first couldn't quite distinguish the exact problem but figured with this code you would be able to get it fairly close :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void picArrow_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    bool movedUp, movedDown, movedLeft, movedRight;

    if (e.X == mPointDown.X) { movedRight = movedLeft = false; }
    else { movedRight = e.X < mPointDown.X; movedLeft = !movedRight; }

    if (e.Y == mPointDown.Y) { movedUp = movedDown = false; }
    else { movedUp = e.Y < mPointDown.Y; movedDown = !movedUp; }

    // Code can now use the Booleans above as needed
    // . . .
}
```